# Create GUI in SceneBuilder(FXML) instead of Java code

Tags: events, javafx, drag-and-drop, fxml, scenebuilder

My JavaFX code creates a stage which contains a simple text field. This field allows a user to drag-and-drop text into it, so it can parse out the text/html componenets.

Currently the text field and stage are created in Java code, but I'd like to design the GUI in Scene Builder. Two questions:

1. How do I convert the Java code into FXML?
2. How do I change the `textfield` into a `textarea` so it can be larger?

Other stages that I've designed in Scene Builder have been created like:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("menu.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        Controller controller = loader.getController();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 420, 580);
        controller.setPrimaryScene(scene);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("styleMain.css");
        primaryStage.setTitle("Demo");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
```

But my Java code uses `DragEvent`s and lambdas so I'm confused how to approach this. Does the event handler code remain in Java, and the design code transfer to FXML somehow?

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(final ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, final String oldValue, final String newValue) {
                htmlFound = newValue;
                textFound = html2text(newValue);
            }
        });
        textField.setPromptText("Drag data here");
        textField.addEventHandler(
                DragEvent.DRAG_OVER,
                event -> {
                    if (event.getDragboard().hasHtml()) {
                        event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY);
                    }
                    event.consume();
                });
        textField.addEventHandler(
                DragEvent.DRAG_DROPPED,
                event -> {
                    Dragboard dragboard = event.getDragboard();
                    if (event.getTransferMode() == TransferMode.COPY &&
                            dragboard.hasHtml()) {
                        textField.setText(dragboard.getHtml());
                        event.setDropCompleted(true);
                    }
                    event.consume();
                });
        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane(textField);
        stackPane.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(stackPane, 300, 150));
        stage.setTitle("Drag and Drop");
        stage.show();
```

Comment: The event handler code goes in the controller. See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controllers).

Comment: Oh right, thanks James. As for changing textfield to textarea, if I simply rename `TextField textField = new TextField();` to `TextArea textField = new TextArea();` it causes the code to not resolve methods like `textProperty`, `setPromptText` and `addEventHandler`. Can you clarify the proper approach?

Comment: Those methods should all work just fine, as they are defined in `TextInputControl`. Make sure you have the correct import.

Comment: Yep, you're a smart guy. I must've had the wrong import for TextArea. I've successfully integrated the code into FXML too. You've been great. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to change the Java Code to FXML you have to do it manualy I think. I dont know any Tool that can do this for you.